# downloaded video from google photos api do not have best quality

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I am using Google Photos API to download my photos and video.
The [API docs](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items#video-base-urls) say:

> To access the bytes of a video mediaItem, concatenate the baseUrl with the download video, dv parameter.
>
> The dv parameter requests a high quality, transcoded version of the original video. The parameter is not compatible with the w and h parameters.

But video, that downloaded from "base_URL=dv" dont have best quality. 
If i download video with browser from https://photos.google.com/ it have more size (28 MB) and have 60 fps, but the same video from "base_URL=dv" have small size (18 MB) and 30 fps. Audio track in video also below in video downloaded from "base_URL=dv".

How can I get a URL to download a video with original quality (like from the browser) from the Google Photos API?

Comment: If you [inspect network traffic](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) from your browser when downloading the video you can see what URL Photos uses, which might give some clues.

Comment: Yes, i know. But i use google photos api in my programm, and i need to get url to original quality of video from api.

Comment: Understood, I was suggesting trying to reproduce the calls Photos makes in your program.

Answer (score 0):

It took a long time. Maybe you have found a solution to your question. Please share.
I was shown one example "baseUrl=m15". But this does not work with older videos that do not support streaming.

Additionally. It will not be possible to track the network traffic of the browser when loading the google photo page and get examples of url video requests. The page HTML generated url addresses are already written in the JS code of the page. There are no external calls.

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30321763)